# Maximum App Size in custom Dojo builds ?

Tags: javascript, dojo

in my custom Dojo build (using dojo-boilerplate template from Github) my dojo.js outputs only :

//>>built

whilst dojo.js.uncompressed.js contains real code (7.7MB).

I am using the same boiler template for other apps and seems to work only with smaller apps with 3 MB as maximum.

Is there anything I can do ?

There are no errors in my builds, just a few warnings.

Comment: What optimizer are you using?  I've seen that happen with closure when you have syntax it doesn't like such as trailing commas.

Comment: Yes, closure. I've been actually very carefully about trailing commas but I will recheck my code again, so finally thank you for the hint !

Answer (score 0):

It could be that errors are occurring during the compression process but closure is simply too verbose for you to see the errors.  You could try turning down Closure Compiler's logging levels by adding the following line in your profile:

```
var profile = {
//your config here
};

//Dial down the closure verbosity
Packages.com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Packages.java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);
```